# В чём ошибка при удалении блока в JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт добавления блоков на страницу https://jsfiddle.net/7su5s63d/

```
// Добавлене блоков
var div = '';
var next_id = 3;
add_block.onclick = function() {
    next_id++;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 's'+next_id;  
    div.className = 'text block';
    var template = '<div class="labels-intro"><input type="text" class="form-control form-about w100" placeholder="Введите имя поля"></div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove test" aria-hidden="true" id="del'+next_id+'">удалить</span>';
    div.innerHTML = template;
    main.appendChild(div);

    // Удаление блоков
    document.getElementById(div.id).addEventListener('click', function(e) {        
        this.remove();
    });
};
```

Проблема в том, что в добавляемом блоке есть input и по задумке удаляться блок должен только когда в нём будет нажат span со словом удалить, но удаляется блок даже если просто на input нажать. Т.е. ввести в input ничего нельзя, он сразу удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно событие `click` вешать конкретно на `span`, а вы искали елемент по ид `div.id` тоесть это всетаки див, вот он при любом клике и удалялся

```js
// Добавлене блоков
var div = '';
var next_id = 3;
add_block.onclick = function() {
  next_id++;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 's' + next_id;
  div.className = 'text block';
  var template = '<div class="labels-intro"><input type="text" class="form-control form-about w100" placeholder="Ваше имя"></div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove test" aria-hidden="true" id="del' + next_id + '">удалить</span>';
  div.innerHTML = template;
  main.appendChild(div);

  document.getElementById('del' + next_id).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    div.remove();
  });
};
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span id="add_block">+ добавить блок</span><br>
  <div id="s1" class="text block">one</div>
  <div id="s2" class="text block">two</div>
  <div id="s3" class="text block">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    
    // Добавлене блоков
var div = '';
var next_id = 3;
add_block.onclick = function() {
    next_id++;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 's'+next_id;  
    div.className = 'text block';
    var template = '<div class="labels-intro"><input type="text" class="form-control form-about w100" placeholder="Ваше имя"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove test" aria-hidden="true" id="del'+next_id+'">удалить</span></div>';
    div.innerHTML = template;
    main.appendChild(div);
    // Удаление блоков
    document.getElementById('del'+next_id).addEventListener('click', function(e) {        
        this.parentNode.remove();
    });    
};
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span id="add_block">+ добавить блок</span><br>
  <div id="s1" class="text block">one</div>
  <div id="s2" class="text block">two</div>
  <div id="s3" class="text block">three</div>
</div>
```